# Find unused character(s) in string

Tags: r, regex

For a library call I have to provide a separator, which must not occur in the in the text, because otherwise the library call gets confused.

Now I was wondering how I can adapt my code to assure that the separator I use is guaranteed not to occur in the input text.

I am solving this issue with a `while` loop: I make a (hardcoded) assumption about the most unlikely string in the input, check if it is present and if so, just enlarges the string. This works but feels very hackish, so I was wondering whether there is a more elegant version (e.g. an existing base R function, or a loop free solution), which does the same for me? Ideally the found separator is also minimal in length.

I could simply hardcode a large enough set of potential separators and look for the first one not occuring in the text, but this may also break at some point if all of these sepeatirs happen to occur in my input.

Reasoning for that is that even if it will never happen (well never say never), I am afraid that in some distant future there will be this one input string which requires thousands of `while` loops before finding an unused string.

```
input_string <- c("a/b", "a#b", "a//b", "a-b", "a,b", "a.b")
orig_sep <- sep <- "/" ## first guess as a separator
while(any(grepl(sep, input_string, fixed = TRUE))) {
  sep <- paste0(sep, orig_sep)
}
print(sep)
# "///"
```

Comment: So if the sep was`+` then the output would `+`, and that is the sep we want use, right? But we want to guess that `+`, right?

Comment: What happens if input used ALL the possible characters?

Comment: In this case the separator should be using a string of 2 characters like `++`

Comment: Added regex tag to invite the regex masters.

Comment: Yes, I simply want to find a separator (of minimal length) which is guaranteed not to occur in the text. It could be any character. In my example all of the following characters would do `'+' 'z' '_' '++'` and so on. But how to determine this separator programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case 1 ASCII can be found you can use `table`.

```
tt <- table(factor(strsplit(paste(input_string, collapse = ""), "")[[1]]
       , rawToChar(as.raw(32:126), TRUE)))
names(tt)[tt==0]
```

`rawToChar(as.raw(32:126), TRUE)` gives you all ASCII's, which are used as factor levels. And `table` counts all cases. If there is at least one `0` you can use it.

In case you need 2 ASCII you can try the following returning all possible delimiters:

```
x <- rawToChar(as.raw(32:126), TRUE)
x <- c(outer(x, x, paste0))
x[!sapply(x, function(y) {any(grepl(y, input_string, fixed=TRUE))})]
```

Or for n-ASCII:

```
orig_sep  <- x <- rawToChar(as.raw(32:126), TRUE)
sep  <- x[0]
repeat {
  sep <- x[!sapply(x, function(y) {any(grepl(y, input_string, fixed=TRUE))})]
  if(length(sep) > 0) break;
  x <- c(outer(x, orig_sep, paste0))
}
sep
```

Search for 1-2 ASCII with only a `sapply`-loop and taking separator with minimal length.

```
x <- rawToChar(as.raw(32:126), TRUE)
x <- c(x, outer(x, x, paste0))
x[!sapply(x, function(y) {any(grepl(y, input_string, fixed=TRUE))})][1]
#[1] " "
```

In case you want to know how many times a character needs to be repeated to work as a separator, as you do it in the question, you can use `gregexpr`.

```
strrep("/", max(sapply(gregexpr("/*", input_string)
  , function(x) max(attributes(x)$match.length)))+1)
#[1] "///"

strrep("/", max(c(0, sapply(gregexpr("/+", input_string)
  , function(x) max(attributes(x)$match.length))))+1)
#[1] "///"
```

Comment: Like this idea, but there may be cases where I need a length 2 separator in case all the ASCII's are used...

Comment: Ok, instead of a `while` we have now a `repeat`, so I guess that some sort of loop is necessary anyways, so my code snippet would do. But thanks for your creative solution +1.

Comment: @thothal You can do it with one `sapply`-loop, but then you have to say before how long the separator can be. I have added a solution for case 1-2 ASCII.

Comment: Which I cannot. Because the input is out of my control, so nobody can prevent that there is this one input which uses a string which contains all ASCIIs in tuples like `'//++##&&...'` would be a valid string.

Comment: Beautiful, your last solution is exactly what I was looking for. Final code for reference: `strrep("/", max(sapply(gregexpr("/+", input_string), purrr::attr_getter("match.length"))) + 1)`

Comment: @thothal `gregexpr("/+", input_string)` will give you `-1` in case it will not find it, what will result in an empty string as the result. So either you change it to `/*` or add `0` to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I made some benchmarks, and the sad news is that only if we have a lot of occurrences of the separator in the input string the `regex` solution will pay off. I won't expect long repetitions of the separator, so from that perspective the `while` solution should be preferable, but it would be the first time in my `R` life that I actually had to rely on a `while` construct.

**Code**

```
library(microbenchmark)
sep <- "/"

make_input <- function(max_occ, vec_len = 1000) {
   paste0("A", strrep(sep, sample(0:max_occ, vec_len, TRUE)))
}

set.seed(1)

no_occ   <- make_input(0)
typ_occ  <- make_input(1)
mid_occ  <- make_input(10)
high_occ <- make_input(100)

while_fun <- function(in_str) {
  my_sep <- sep
  while(any(grepl(my_sep, in_str, fixed = TRUE))) {
    my_sep <- paste0(my_sep, sep)
  }
  my_sep
}

greg_fun <- function(in_str) {
 strrep(sep, 
    max(sapply(gregexpr(paste0(sep, "+"), in_str), 
               purrr::attr_getter("match.length")), 0) + 1)
}

microbenchmark(no_occ_w   = while_fun(no_occ),
               no_occ_r   = greg_fun(no_occ),
               typ_occ_w  = while_fun(typ_occ),
               typ_occ_r  = greg_fun(typ_occ),
               mid_occ_w  = while_fun(mid_occ),
               mid_occ_r  = greg_fun(mid_occ),
               high_occ_w = while_fun(high_occ),
               high_occ_r = greg_fun(high_occ))
```

**Results**

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval  cld
   no_occ_w   12.3   13.30   15.947   14.60   16.55   51.1   100 a   
   no_occ_r 1074.8 1184.90 1981.637 1253.45 1546.20 7037.9   100  b  
  typ_occ_w   33.8   36.00   42.842   38.55   41.45  229.2   100 a   
  typ_occ_r 1090.4 1192.15 2090.526 1283.80 1547.10 8490.7   100  b  
  mid_occ_w  277.9  283.35  336.466  288.30  309.45 3452.2   100 a   
  mid_occ_r 1161.6 1269.50 2204.213 1368.45 1789.20 7664.7   100  b  
 high_occ_w 3736.4 3852.95 4082.844 3962.30 4097.60 6658.3   100    d
 high_occ_r 1685.5 1776.15 2819.703 1868.10 4065.00 7960.9   100   c
```